# Display symbology categories at certain scales with ArcGis Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, scale

We can since a long time display layers at certain scales but 
is it possible to display a specific symbology categories at certain scales ?

For example if I have the following feature layer:

[image]

Can I display the tertiary road only until the scale 1:20000 ?

ArcGis Pro have an option "Enable scale-based sizing" but I'm only able to increase the size of one specific categorie at lower scale but i'm not able to prevent arcgis to display this categorie at lower scale.

Comment: My Bad, I found the answer immediately after asking the question, I just added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, You can simply add a new size stop and fixe the value at 0pt.

So for example if I do that:

[image]

My lines won't display if the scale is lower than 1:50000